# command line utility for changing file labels

Tags: macos, command-line, colors, finder, label

is there a command line utility for changing the color label of files in macosx?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/168927/mac-os-x-how-to-change-the-color-label-of-files-from-the-terminal Basically, use AppleScript.

Answer (score 3):

You can write it yourself. Open `/Applications/Utilities/AppleScript Editor.app` and enter the following:

```
on run argv
    tell application "Finder"
        set theFile to POSIX file (item 1 of argv) as alias
        set labelIdx to (item 2 of argv as number)
        set label index of theFile to labelIdx
    end tell
end run
```

Save as `color.scpt` and invoke from Terminal like this:

```
osascript color.scpt somefile.txt 3
```

`somefile.txt` will be colored, `3` is the color: `0` means colorless, 1 through 7 are the Finder's colors (with `1` being red).

Answer (score 0):

This article, [View and set Labels from the command line](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20031030221241557), describes a command line utility to do it.  Caveat: it's an old article, describing a utility for OS 10.3, and I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the responses here and in referenced posts, I made the following function and added it to my ~/.bash_profile file:

```
# Set Finder label color
label(){
  if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    echo "USAGE: label [0-7] file1 [file2] ..."
    echo "Sets the Finder label (color) for files"
    echo "Default colors:"
    echo " 0  No color"
    echo " 1  Orange"
    echo " 2  Red"
    echo " 3  Yellow"
    echo " 4  Blue"
    echo " 5  Purple"
    echo " 6  Green"
    echo " 7  Gray"
  else
    osascript - "$@" << EOF
    on run argv
        set labelIndex to (item 1 of argv as number)
        repeat with i from 2 to (count of argv)
          tell application "Finder"
              set theFile to POSIX file (item i of argv) as alias
              set label index of theFile to labelIndex
          end tell
        end repeat
    end run
EOF
  fi
}
```

>

Comment: Didn't you get the order wrong? Red is before orange, isn't it?

Comment: @Daniel No, the default order of colors sucks. You could actually edit your answer to take it into account.