# Mac OS X Finder: Folder Color Labels are not staying across computers on connected to SAN

Tags: macos, mac, colors, cache, finder

I'm trying to label certain folders on a SAN drive, however certain computers can see these colors and others cannot.

I'm curious if there's a way to clear the finder cache for the color labels, as I believe that might be the issue but I'm not sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Information about color label is stored inside of .DS_Store file. Your users most probably cannot read this file because of permissions problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Lion, at least, labels are stored in the extended attribute, `kMDItemFSLabel`, not `.DS_Store` files (see here [Mac OS X: How to change the color label of files from the Terminal](https://superuser.com/questions/168927/mac-os-x-how-to-change-the-color-label-of-files-from-the-terminal)). You can read this metadata from a file: `mdls -name kMDItemFSLabel /path/to/file.ext`. I've not tried to read these attributes over a network, but if doing so fails for you, maybe `mdls` will throw a useful error.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. However, mdls just fails with:
`/volume1/bertha.txt: could not find /volume1/bertha.txt.`

Comment: does `ls /volume1/bertha.txt` return the file or an error message?

Comment: It returns the file just fine.